# Como utilizar el regex y split en java

Tags: java, regex

Amigos, un gusto saludarlos, tengo un pequeño problema con expresiones regulares, lo que pasa es que tengo una cadena que quiero dividir que sería la siguiente:

```
CVE_TIPO_VALOR_NVA | CVE_INSTRUMENTO_NVA | CVE_SERIE_NVA
```

Por ejm, en tres cadenas separadas, es decir,

```
CVE_TIPO_VALOR_NVA
CVE_INSTRUMENTO_NVA
CVE_SERIE_NVA
```

Y guardarlas en un arreglo de cadenas, hay alguna forma de poder hacerlo, la verdad con expresiones regulares no he trabajado mucho, miren este es mi codigo:

```
JSONObject valoresRecibir =(JSONObject) transaccionesItem.get("valoresRecibir"); //Dalta otra validacion de ISIN
  if(valoresRecibir!=null){
  String description =(String) valoresRecibir.get("description");
  if(description!=null){
    if(description.equals("CVE_TIPO_VALOR_NVA | CVE_INSTRUMENTO_NVA | CVE_SERIE_NVA")){                                                 
      String dcveTipoValorNva = description;
      String [] divisor = dcveTipoValorNva.split("|");
      System.out.println("Dividos...");
      System.out.println("parteCveValorT..."+ divisor[0]);
      System.out.println("parteCveInsNva..."+ divisor[1]);
      System.out.println("parteCveSerieNva..."+ divisor[2]);
      System.out.println("-------------------------------");
      System.out.println("Si entre :V "+ dcveTipoValorNva.toString());

      /*String string = "123-654321";
      String[] parts = string.split("-");
      String part1 = parts[0]; // 123
      String part2 = parts[1]; // 654321*/
    }
  }
}
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar y explicarme que significa cada elemento de la expresión regular por favor, quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios, saludos

Answer (score 1):

En expresiones regulares puedes usar la barra inversa `\` para escapar al siguiente carácter de la expresión de búsqueda, siendo así:

- `\|`  = caracter pipe.
- `\s`  = un espacio en blanco.
- `\s+` = uno o    mas espacios en blanco.

Para este escenario en concreto es posible haciendo uso de la regex de la siguiente manera:

`String [] divisor = dcveTipoValorNva.split("\\s+\\|\\s+");`

En donde basicamente buscará un patrón conformado por el carácter *pipe* `\\|` el cual esté precedido y seguido por uno o mas espacios en blanco `\\s+`

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, me sirvió bastante y que padre que pusiste que es cada simbolo de los regex, en verdad gracias, saludos JohnnyTB